# How to read json object from cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

I use jquery.cookie to store my client-side application cookies and some of these cookies contains JSON.

This is my script so far

```
trigger.on('click touchend', function () {
    var StoredSettings = $.cookie('qlToggled'),
        isToggled = 0,
        offset = -300,
        endpoint = 15,
        triggerX = $('#leftcolumn').offset().left + $('#leftcolumn').width();

    if (typeof StoredSettings !== 'undefined') {
        isToggled = StoredSettings.toggled;
        offset = StoredSettings.cOffset;
        endpoint = StoredSettings.cEndpoint;
        triggerX = StoredSettings.cTriggerX;
    }

    if (isToggled == '1') {
        offset = 0;
        endpoint = 315;
        triggerX = $('#leftcolumn').width();
        var cookieValues = { toggled: '0', cOffset: offset, cEndpoint: endpoint, cTriggerX: triggerX };
        $.cookie('qlToggled', JSON.stringify(cookieValues), { expires: 365, path: '/', json: true });
    }
    else {
        var cookieValues = { toggled: '1', cOffset: offset, cEndpoint: endpoint, cTriggerX: triggerX };
        $.cookie('qlToggled', JSON.stringify(cookieValues), { expires: 365, path: '/', json: true });
    }

    $('#leftcolumn').animate({ 'left': offset }, speeding);
    $('#content').animate({ 'margin-left': endpoint }, speeding);
    trigger.animate({ 'left': triggerX }, speeding);
});
```

I use FireBug to see which cookies are saved and the cookie created in the above script is successfully created and I have tried to iterate the values using `$.each(object, function(i ,e))` to see if anything came out and there did.

I'd prefer to NOT having to iterate through the values and just use chainable code as seen within the first if-statement.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: try changing this var StoredSettings = $.cookie('qlToggled') to var StoredSettings = JSON.parse($.cookie('qlToggled'))

Comment: @MelanciaUK Solved it. Post as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Posted. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.parseJSON()` to achieve that.

> jQuery.parseJSON(json)
>
> Returns: Object
>
> Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting
>   JavaScript object.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 8):

That worked with me

**PHP Code**

```
setcookie('message', json_encode(['body'=>'Erro meu amigo', 'type'=>'danger']));
```

**JS code**

```
window.onload = function()
{
    rc = Cookie.get('message'); //rc == result cookie

    if (rc.boolean === true) {
        var data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(rc.data));
        alert(data.body.replace('+', ' '));
    }
}
```